# Heroku and amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2, acl, amazon-vpc

Do Heroku apps run on default VPC or do they run on custom VPC? (I assume by now everyone is using VPC and not the older EC2-Classic)

Does anyone one have information about the VPC id of Heroku (if they are using a custom VPC)?

Earlier they used the AWS account number: 098166147350
as per [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=481999).
Do they still use the same account?
But, Heroku has recommended not to use account id to control access at  [Heroku DevCenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/353).

My idea is to restrict access to my service only to the VPC heroku is using. Also, I want to add a VPC peering connection from my VPC.
On top of this, I will add other security features to further restrict access only to the relevant apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's cedar stack currently still runs on EC2 classic.
The beta [private spaces](https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces) allow you to create a VPC and host your apps inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is really useful.